# Adding view controller to uiview with constraints

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

In a storyboard, I have a 3 screens (controller view):
1) Controller "main" containing a uiview named cntdetail and a button named viewswitch
2) Controller "A" with several elements (label, textfields...)
3) Controller "B" with also several elements

What I need it to load the view A in cntdetail when the view appears and switch from A to B when tapping the button and vice versa.

What I'm doing (it is in C# but nearly like swift):

In the Main ViewDidLoad:

```
cviewA = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SaisieVocale");
cviewB = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SaisieDetaillee");
AddChildViewController(cviewA);
AddChildViewController(cviewB);
viewAcontenth = GetContentHeight(cviewA.View); //a personal function that calculate the height of the content, it works
viewBcontenth = GetContentHeight(cviewB.View);
```

when clicking the button (and nearly the same in viewdidappear) (I use A to simplify but it is once A once B):

```
cviewB.View.RemoveFromSuperview();

//change the height constraint of the uiview to fit the height of my views 
        foreach (var cst in cntdetails.Constraints)
        {
            if ((UIView)cst.FirstItem == cntdetails || (UIView)cst.SecondItem == cntdetails)
            {
                if (cst.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height)                               //il faut modifier la contrainte de hauteur
                    cst.Constant = viewAcontenth;
            }
        }
cntdetails.AddSubview(cviewA.View);
```

But it doesn't work as expected, the hiehgt of the main view is increased a bit each time I click the button and one of the view (A or B) in not visible.

EDIT: cntdetails has equal constraint at top, leading, trailing and height with the main view. Then I just have to modify the height constraint and actualy this part work.

EDIT: I tried to add constrains to keep the size of A and B following the size of cntdetail but it's not better:

```
cviewA.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
cviewA.View.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(cntdetails.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
cviewA.View.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(cntdetails.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
cviewA.View.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(cntdetails.WidthAnchor).Active = true;
cviewA.View.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(cntdetails.HeightAnchor).Active = true;
```

Comment: I think you'd better add some constraints or frame to the view(A or B) so that the view can be shown in the correct position. And is it the problem of the cntdetails's constraints that the height will be larger than last time? You can post some code about autolayout if possible to help us find out the issue.

Comment: I just added exmlpaination for the cntdetail's constraints. This part work, this is the main div that increase its size with an empty space at the bottom.

Comment: I think if you don't set any constraints to the view(A or B). Its content will expand outside of the cntdetail and my be not shown in the window. Since the size of one controller's(in your case cviewA) View is as large as the window.

Comment: I tried several things in fact, like adding 4 constraints to A and B with cntdetail, adding autoresizingmask to A and B or setting their Frame each time and also setting both at the same size and playing with hidden parameter but none of these method worked. So I hope something was wrong with my code and someone told me that's not the way... do that but...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found some mistakes I made. [This page helped](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)
For the main view that increased it was because of my function calculating the view height.

First in the viewdidload:

```
cviewA = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SaisieVocale");
cviewB = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SaisieDetaillee");
//AddChildViewController(cviewA);   no need to do that here
//AddChildViewController(cviewB);
viewAcontenth = GetContentHeight(cviewA.View); //a personal function that calculate the height of the content, it works
viewBcontenth = GetContentHeight(cviewB.View);
```

When switching from A to B :

```
//change the height constraint of the uiview to fit the height of my views 
        foreach (var cst in cntdetails.Constraints)
        {
            if ((UIView)cst.FirstItem == cntdetails || (UIView)cst.SecondItem == cntdetails)
            {
                if (cst.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height)                               //il faut modifier la contrainte de hauteur
                    cst.Constant = viewAcontenth;
            }
        }

//first remove B except the first time
cviewB.DidMoveToParentViewController(null);
cviewB.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
cviewB.RemoveFromParentViewController();

//next add A:
this.AddChildViewController(cviewA);
cviewA.View.Frame= cntdetails.Bounds;
cntdetails.AddSubview(cviewA.View);
cviewA.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
```